# Get certificate selected by window.crypto "ask"

Tags: javascript, firefox, certificate, mozilla, cryptoapi

anyone knows how you can get on javascript which certificate do you select from the pop-up of window.crypto.signText("xxxxx","ask")?
On Firefox, just in case :)
I'm using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_crypto but i can't believe you have a method to select a certificate of firefox store and you can't know from code which certificate was selected.
Regards.

Comment: These functions have just been removed from Firefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1030963 so you should not be using them.

Comment: But then what should be doing if you want to register the public key of a user on a system? this is something i need to do